# Cannot download log files through `WebClient.DownloadFile` method in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logfile, webclient

I am using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` method for downloading files through my Localhost URL.
And it is working well for all files except for log files. When I download log files it shows contents as "Not Authorized"
Also it occurred to me than when I open log files in browser through URL then it won't show its contents in browser as "Not Authorized"

Is there a way to access contents of log file through `WebClient.DownloadFile()` method.

I want to download these files with its content into the specified location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving your log in `.txt` format.

I faced similar problem once. Then I updated code which generates the `.log` files. And change the file extension to `.txt` which means the files which will be generated will be of `.txt` format and not `.log` format.

Generating `.txt` files for log will be helpful for downloading it via specified method.